Fix NPM packages that have vulnerabilites
i was writing a project using node.js and i use a command line
npm install

there are alot of vulnerabilites.
Packages.json

{
  "name": "pretty-chat-react-typescript",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "antd": "^4.21.5",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "npm-force-resolutions": "^0.0.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chat-engine-advanced": "0.1.21",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


i tried
npm audit

and then use
npm audit fix

it fix alot of packages except for 10 packages,
i tried
npm audit fix --force

but it break some of the packages
i tried overriders, but it make it worse please help

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If there are no serious attachments to npm, probably consider switching to pnpm or yarn.

meaning  of  serious attachments

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
